# Socket.io, can't emit custom event from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have a very simple app, with client-side JS supposed to get the data from a form and send it to the server through a `data` event.

Here is the server-side code:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    http        = require('http').Server(app),
    io          = require('socket.io')(http);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Client connected');
});
io.sockets.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

http.listen(8080);
```

And here is the client-side code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

$('#send').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('data', {
        transportation: $('#transportation').val(),
        distance: $('#distance').val()
    });
});
```

In the server-side console, I see the `connection` event is correctly received, but not the `data` one…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the handler on the client socket as follows:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Client connected');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

http.listen(8080);
```